# How to sense channel in Contiki?

Tags: contiki, cooja

What is the function call or set of instructions required to **perform channel sensing** in MAC layer of Contiki?

I want to test custom MAC protocols, so for example in CSMA, channel sensing is required before transmission.

I have gone through 'contiki/core/net/mac/csma.c' to see how they have done channel sensing. But I could only see scheduling of queue packets and status checks.

**How are they checking if channel is busy before transmission**?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
if(NETSTACK_RADIO().channel_clear()) {
  printf("channel not busy\n");
} else {
  printf("channel busy\n");
}
```

The channel check is implemented in the radio driver. Contiki has platform independent radio API. The actual, platform-specific driver is available through `NETSTACK_RADIO` API, as demonstrated above. The check is used b the RDC (radio duty cycling) layer, for example, ContikiMAC.

Comment: thank you for the answer. So how is CSMA doing channel check? I didn't see this function call in *csma.c*.

Comment: It does not. The RDC layer (between the MAC and the radio) does that.

Comment: channel sensing is an important part of any MAC design. So if I want to implement a custom MAC, should I create new MAC and RDC source files? (like _csma.c_)